# How to refresh content in fancy scroll view of UI Extension at runtime Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am adding prefab in content at runtime but its not refreshing with new content and I am using fancy scroll view of example of UI extension How can I do that(Fancy scroll example 07)

Comment: What do you mean by fancy scroll? what script do you use to add a new prefab? what is the prefab? there is so much information missing on this post

Comment: hi noam fancy scroll(example 07) is the example in the UI extension package. i want to generate prefab in content through my own script at runtime prefab is generally a image

Comment: again, please provide an image of your game object from your hierarchy and from your inspector, if you already try something please add your script to this post